# \operatorname produces ∓ instead of a hyphen

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, stix

If I compile

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\operatorname{some-operator}$
\end{document}
```

then I get the output

> some∓operator

How do I address this problem?

Comment: Try and retype the - with the - sign on your keyboard.

Comment: I remove some packages and reinsert them to test which package produces the problem. It seems that Stix mess with the ascii encoding. Thank you guys :)

Comment: It would have saved others time if you'd included a MWE to begin with.

Comment: @Teepeemm 6....

Answer (score 2):

The default LaTeX definition is via

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{-}{\mathbin}{symbols}{"00}
```

which means that `-` gets a mathcode of `0x2200`.

But if you load stix, then amsmath:

- stix changes the mathcode to `0x202A` making it using the "operators" font,
- the amsmath `\operatorname` uses also the "operators" font, but the famous `\newmcodes@` macro forcefully assigns a math code of `0x0045` to the hyphen character.

Turns out that in the "operators" font set-up by stix, there is the character you see at this location. (the font macro is `\LS1/stix/m/n`)

So the minimal example is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\operatorname{foo-bar}$
\end{document}
```

The documentation of stix does recommend to load amsmath *after*, though :-(

possible (not very useful) work-around

```
\makeatletter
$\operatorname{foo\mathord{\std@minus}bar}$
```

ah ok there is a patch in the `stix` package

```
\@ifpackageloaded{amsopn}{
    \begingroup \catcode`\"=12
    \gdef\newmcodes@{%
      \mathcode`\'="007F\relax%
      \mathcode`\*="003C\relax%
      \mathcode`\.="613A\relax%
      \ifnum\mathcode`\-="002A \else
        \mathchardef\std@minus\mathcode`\-\relax
      \fi
      \mathcode`\-="002A\relax%
      \mathcode`\/="005F\relax%
      \mathcode`\:="603A\relax%
    }
    \endgroup
}{}
```

Thus you should simply execute the code which is within braces, within `\makeatletter/\makeatother` after having loaded `amsmath` (in the case where it is loaded after `stix`).

Comment: as usual with end-user documentation things such as "With amsmath v2.14 or newer, it is recommended to load it (and/or packages that load it) _after_ the stix package" are useless because they don't give any clue about the underlying rationale. Thus,  perhaps the best is to 1) load `amsopn`, 2) load `stix`, 3) load `amsmath` but without time wasted into testing one can not tell. I am suspicious of recommendation of loading a package later than one's own, why not tell the user you must load `amsmath` first? Then stix can do whatever it wants even modify things done by amsmath at begin document.

Comment: Excellent answer.  @CRC: see how much better an answer one gets with a MWE?

Comment: @JPi I am new here and I work on a project with a relative big header. At the point I asked the question I wasn't aware that it is caused by stix and I wasn't sure how I create an MWE in this scenario. I am very very thankful for your excellent help :)